# Luatex and system luarocks mismatch problem

Tags: luatex

I've been working on using lua to read a yaml file and print out a nice latex table but I've hit a snag. My lua code uses lyaml installed using luarocks, but luarocks only sees my system lua, which is 5.3. This makes it that when I install luarocks, and try to compile my files using lualatex, it fails. Encouragingly, it points towards the correct installation location, so i know its looking in the right place, but it says that the module is for 5.3, and that 5.2 is required.

It seems that some files in texlive's distribution point towards an option of lua 5.3, and miktex already allows for choosing between 5.2 and 5.3, but I haven't been able to find any information on how to make that change, or if it is indeed possible. Is there a solution to this or do I have to wait for texlive to use luatex compiled with lua 5.3?

This is all done on a fedora 29 system with the current version of texlive 2018.

Comment: By default `/usr/local/bin/luatex` is a symlink to `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/luatex`.  You can change that link to `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/luatex53`.  (You will probably have to rebuild the format using `fmtutil-sys --byfmt=lualatex`)

Comment: Oh Wow, thank you! this was exactly what I needed, also, learned something about texlive internals, neat. For anyone else looking for the solution, in fedora the paths are instead /usr/bin/lulatex which is a symbolic link to either /usr/bin/luatex or /usr/bin/lutex53 depending on which version you want (5.2 or 5.3)

Comment: Do you happen to have any references on how to get luarocks set up with a luatex installation, without a system lua?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I tried looking at the LuaRocks installation guide as well and it doesn't really give any indication of how that could be done